# Calling GetBalance function in Paypal Merchant API

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to call the GetBalance function in the Paypal API, using permissions that were granted using the Permissions API. I redirect a user to Paypal, where the ACCOUNT_BALANCE permission is granted - that returns to my app a request token and a verification code.

Does anyone know how I use these with the GetBalance function though?  The sample code in the SDK calls the GetBalance function using UserName, Password and Signature parameters, but I need to get the balance of a third party user, not the balance of my own account, and I won't have that users password or signature, I only have the request token and verification code sent back to me when they granted permissions.

Any ideas?
(working in ASP.Net btw!)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every call will have [those three things](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/gs_PayPalAPIs/#request), period. Your API username, API password and an API signature. That doesn't change between calls.

[GetBalance](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetBalance_API_Operation_NVP/) is typically used to get your Paypal balance. Now, there is a way to get a third party balance. If they have authorized your API username, you can run calls on their behalf. In that case, you use your API credentials but pass another parameter in your call. That parameter ([SUBJECT](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/NVPAPIOverview/), under Specifying an API Credential Using Signatures) is their email associated with that account. Then, and only then, can you retrieve their Paypal account balance.

Comment: Great - thanks for that! I think part of the problem also was that I was using the paypal sdk, with the component they provide with it, which doesn't make it obvious how to use the API. After reading your post & links, I've created a service reference & wsdl and it's making a lot more sense how it all fits together. Thx again!